# Multiple methods warning

Tags: objective-c

I'm currently learning Objective C and in the process I've made the silly little program below. The program compiles fine - however I get the warning "multiple methods named '-setName:' found".

I've only interfaced and implemented the method once.

What does this warning mean, and how do I correct it?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// these are the three yoga-exercises we can perform

typedef enum {
    kCobra,
    kUniversal,
    kDog
} ExerciseName;

// translating our variables into human

NSString *nameExercise (ExerciseName nameExercise)
{
    switch (nameExercise) {
        case kCobra:
            return @"Cobra Pose";
            break;
        case kUniversal:
            return @"Universal Stretch";
            break;
        case kDog:
            return @"Dog Pose";
            break;
    }

    return @"no clue!";

} // nameExercise


@interface Exercise : NSObject
{
    ExerciseName name;
}

-(void) setName: (ExerciseName) name;
-(void) exerciseDo;

@end


@implementation Exercise

-(void) setName: (ExerciseName) n {
    name = n;
} // setName

-(void) exerciseDo {
    NSLog(@"Exercise: %@",
          nameExercise(name));
}

@end


void executeExercises(id exercises[], int count) {

    int i;

    for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
        id exercise = exercises[i];
        [exercise exerciseDo];
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    id exercises[1];

    exercises[0] = [Exercise new]; // initiating an object of class Exercise
    [exercises[0]   setName:kDog];

    executeExercises(exercises, 1);

    return 0;

} //main
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the meaning of the message is that there are multiple selectors with the name `setName:` in the translation (that is, it is declared in at least on other place among all included headers). the compiler may choose the wrong selector (which can introduce undefined behavior).

you can typically correct the problem using one (or more) of the following approaches:

1) rename the method to a unique name: e.g. `setExerciseName` may be ok, if not used in other translations.

2) match the signature of the other selector. e.g. `setName:(NSString *)name`

3) use type safety:

```
Exercise * ex = [Exercise new];
[ex setName:kCobra];
```

4) cast the variable to the type: `[(Exercise*)exercise setName:kCobra];`

5) restore the type with a new variable: `Exercise * ex = exercise;`

since you have declared the var as an `id`, you have erased the type, and it means that the object may respond any visible selector. in general, you should not erase the type in this manner, except when truly necessary.

the best approach i see is a combination of 1 and 3:

```
[ex setExerciseName:kCobra];
```

Comment: +1.  Think of it this way... if, six months from now, someone you've never met had to read your code, what line of code would make the most sense and give the reader the most understanding of your intentions?