# IOS 7.1 NSMutableDictionary valueForKey count

Tags: nsmutabledictionary, ios7.1

Running into a really weird error.
I have updated xcode to the newest version and therefore compiling my app with IOS7.1, this works great in the simulator, but when i try to Archive the app for distribution i get an error with this code line:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(self.count == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return [[self.meetings valueForKey:[[[self.meetings allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
    }
}
```

The error is this line:

```
    return [[self.meetings valueForKey:[[[self.meetings allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
```

And the error message is:

> Multiple methods named 'count' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Anybody else have this issue after updating to IOS 7.1?

**/* EDIT */**

Found the solution by typecasting.

```
return [(NSMutableArray *) [self.meetings valueForKey:[[[self.meetings allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to split this line into several lines using local variables, e.g. obtain sorted array, take object at index, get value for key, return count. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313294/multiple-methods-named-count-found-with-mismatched-result-parameter-type-or-a