# Xcode 6.1 : Multiple methods named 'count' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Tags: ios, methods, compiler-errors, xcode6.1

I'm getting **Multiple methods named 'count' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes error while building app**. The app was working fine in 32 bit. I have changed it to 64 bit as per [Apple guideline](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172014b).  I have referred this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313294/multiple-methods-named-count-found-with-mismatched-result-parameter-type-or-a) but don't got any help.

I have tested app on multiple devices on simulator. **It works fine on 32 bit but prompts error in 64 bit.**
Why is this so?

```
 -(void)serviceSuccessFulForPatientSelect:(id)response
{
    [self hideOverlay];
    if([response isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        if([response count]>0)
        {
            if(1)
            {
               ...
            }
        }
    }
    [refillDetailTable reloadData];

}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Try to cast response to NSArray before calling "count".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
I had declared **count as property in a view controller**. I renamed it to **CountValue** and the problem got solved.

**Solution 2:**
You can type-cast to appropriate datatype.

```
if([(NSArray *) response count]>0) {
  ...
}
```

This solution was not feasible in my case since there were 1000s of place containing `[response count]`.

Answer (score 33):

```
if([response count]>0)
```

`response` is an `id` here, the error suggests there are multiple methods called `count` which return different types - `int` and `NSInteger` I think are different in 64-bit but the same in 32.

To fix, perform a cast:

```
if([(NSArray*)response count]>0)
```

Comment: It's not feasible for casting since there are around 1000s places to be changed...Any other fix

Comment: Thousands of places? Your alternative is to find the other count method (presumably in your code) and change the return type. But if you have thousands of id objects you're counting, that sounds wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your response, is there any property with name **count**

Comment: if it has whats the problem?