# MBProgressHUD setProgress in iOS 17

Tags: mbprogresshud, ios17

I'm using an older pod, the MBProgressHUD, that is returning an error when trying to run on iOS 17.0:

```
Multiple methods named 'setProgress:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes.
```

It's fairly deeply integrated into the app so I would like to edit it as little as possible. Any idea on the best solution? [I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27739887/944766) options to type-cast **id**, but I'm a bit unsure about what to cast it to?

[image: Screenshoot on the MBProgressHUD error]

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
[(id)indicator setProgress:progress];
```

to

```
[[indicator class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setProgress:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Type-casting it to UIProgressView seemed to do the trick, i.e. from

```
[(id)indicator setProgress:progress];
```

to

```
[(UIProgressView*)indicator setProgress:progress];
```